# What is the maximum number of faces in a triangular mesh of n vertices in 3 dimensions?

Tags: graphics, 3d, mesh

In 2D the maximum number of faces for **n** vertices in a 'perfect'(non-overlapping) mesh is **f = 2n - 4**. Is there an equivalent result for 3 dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) `chi` is defined as:

```
chi = V - E + F
```

where `V`, `E`, and `F` are the numbers of vertices, edges and faces, respectively.

For closed triangular meshes, we know that each edge has two incident faces and each face has three incident edges. Therefore:

```
3 * F = 2 * E
E = 3/2 * F
```

Hence,

```
chi = V - 3/2 * F + F
    = V - 1/2 F
  F = 2 * (V - chi)
```

In the 2D case for planar graphs, `chi` is `2`, resulting in your definition `F = 2 * V - 4`.

For any 3D surface, the Euler characteristic can be calculated from its genus. In general, the more handles the surface has, the smaller its Euler characteristic. Hence, `chi` (and by that `F`) is not limited. However, for a fixed surface topology, the number of faces (relative to the number of vertices) is fixed.

Comment: are there bounds for chi in a 3D closed triangular mesh?

Comment: The Euler characteristic can also be calculated from the first three Betti numbers: `chi = b0 - b1 + b2`. `b0` is the number of connected components (and fixed to 1 for a single mesh). `b1` is the number of 1D holes (and therefore not limited) and `b2` is the number of 2D holes (also not limited). Therefore, `chi` has no theoretical bounds.